Subscription in Unity of Apple app store app
I want to check if user cancelled the subscription of my ios app. I want to show offer price to user. I tried Subscription Manager class of InAppPurchasing but it's always returning false value for isCancelled and always showing true value for isAutoRenewing... Can anyone help?
 I want to access isAutoRenewing value and isCancel value of subscription for Apple App Store

